# Moq does It.Is<List<List<string>>>(x => x.Count == 10) do what I think it should do?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am passing this into the constructor of an object I am unit testing

```
It.Is<List<List<string>>>(x => x.Count == 10)
```

but when I step into the constructor, this statement resolves to null instead of a a `List<List<string>>` with a Count of 10. Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Comment: What were you expecting?

Comment: a List<List<string>> with a Count of 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `It.Is` method is not meant to be called. Actually, I think it should just throw, instead of returning the default value of the type.

It is meant to be used in the expression trees used to setting expectations:

```
interface IFoo { bool DoSomething(IList<IList<string>> strings); }

var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.Setup(f => f.DoSomething(It.Is<IList<IList<string>>>(l => l.Count == 10))
    .Returns(true);
```

The example sets up a mock object of `IFoo` that will return true when passed an `IList<IList<string>>` object with 10 elements. This means that after the following call, `result` will be true:

```
IList<IList<string>> listWith10Elements = // create a list with 10 elements
bool result = mock.Object.DoSomething(listWith10Elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing something into the constructor of an object, you would normally use the proxy object from a mock, with `Setup` on that mock providing any context which your class needs.

For instance:

```
var mock = new Mock<List<List<string>>>();
mock.Setup(x => x.Count()).Returns(10);

var myClass = new MyClass(mock.Object);
```

Use `Verify` to check interactions. What you have there is a matcher, which you can use in `Setup` and `Verify` to match particular types of arguments.

Except, of course, that you won't be able to mock `List` because it doesn't have the virtual methods you're after. Try using, and mocking, `ICollection<List<string>>` instead.

I think this should do what you want. [Hope this helps.](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart)

Comment: ICollection doesn't work either. I don't have access to the mock.Object

Comment: It's a property on `Mock`. If you're creating a new mock, you'll have access to `Mock.Object`. So do `new Mock<ICollection<List<string>>>()` and then `mock.Object` - you'll find you have access, honestly. `IList` should work too.